# Have two different Implementations for an interface execute on different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, future, runnable, callable

I have a interface say `VegetableCreation` with a method:

```
public void writeVeggieDataIntoFile();
```

and two different class called `Apple` and `Mango` that implement `VegetableCreation`.

And there is a factory class `VegetableFactory` with a `create()` method:

```
public class VegetableFactory {
    public VegetableCreation create(String arg0) {

        if (arg0.equals("Apple"))
           return new Apple();
        else if (arg0.equals("Mango")
           return new Mango();
        else {
           // create and return both apple and mango by spawning two different threads
           // so that the writeVeggieDataIntoFile();  gets invoked concurrently
           // for both apple and mango and two different file is created
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm basically trying to achieve here is that when I call the `VegetableFactory` class's `create()` method from a client class's `main()` method and pass any string value other than `"Apple"` or `"Mango"` as a run time argument. I want two different threads to work on each `Apple` and `Mango` object and work concurrently on each `writeVeggieDataIntoFile()` method.

Any suggestion on design strategy / or which concurrent APIs to use etc. would be highly appreciated.

P.S.: I should be calling it fruit** and not vegetable*

Comment: that's pretty straight forward. what strategy have you in mind

Comment: What's the goal of the exercise? Learning low-level thread handling? Learning how to use executors? Learning how to use parallel streams? This doesn't look like a typical use-case where one would use multi-threading, so pick the thing you want to learn (or the thing your teacher wants you to learn).

Comment: @JBNizet I need to do this to write two different fairly large files. Apple and Mango were just an example. If I do it sequentially the process is just too slow. I have barely done much thread handling in real life so wanted to be real careful on how I design it.

Comment: If all you're doing in your method is writing to a file, and both files are on the same disk, making it multi-threaded will probably make it slower, not faster. But you can test it by simply using a parallel stream, or an executor with two threads.

Comment: @shashwatZing If you need to create 2 or more instances and they must run concurrently, you'll need to use threads.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the suggestion. I might be doing some performance matrix by trying out few different approaches and decide on whether to use or not use multiple threads. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the Composite pattern, and then build a CompositeVegetable which when told to "do it's thing" launches two threads, one which does one thing, the other doing the other thing.

```
public class BothVegetable implements Vegetable {
    public void writeVeggieDataInfoFile() {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new AppleRunnable());
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new MangoRunnable());
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
    }
}

// and in your factory

    return new CompositeVegetable();
```

PS.  Your vegetables look like fruits to me!

Comment: Thanks @Edwin Buck. I will give it a try and if it works I would like to thank you in advance. I did put a P.s on the question  P.S.: I should be calling it fruit** and not vegetable*. Was just lazy to change it everywhere.

Comment: I assume `BothVegetable` should be renamed to `CompositeVegetable` and `doIt()` renamed to `writeVeggieDataIntoFile()`?

Comment: Yes, they should be.  Except that other CompositeVegetables might exist, so one needs to come up with a better name that doesn't preclude other CompositeVegetables.  Maybe an `AppleMangoBlastVegetable`?

Comment: @EdwinBuck. So i played around with bunch of different things including executors and parallel streams but your solution did my job in the most simplistic manner. And for that I would like to thank you with a upvote and by accepting your answer.

Comment: @shashwatZing Glad to have helped.  Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect to get a `Vegetable`/`Fruit` from a factory called `VegetableFactory`/`FruitFactory`, not a `VegetableCreation`/`FruitCreation`.

I'd avoid thread creation and file writing as side effects inside a factory method.

I'd also rename/change `writeFruitDataIntoFile()` to `write(Writer out)` since what you write is told by the enclosing interface or class and where you write to is told by its method parameter(s).

If you really need concurrent processing, create a thread in `write(...)` and let the factory method simply return a `Fruit`.

Advantages are:

- No side effects at object creation that have to be documented.
- Threads are created on demand only (in case `write()` is invoked) and not at every `Fruit` object creation.
- You don't need an extra class.
- It's a clean implementation understood at first sight by everybody who knows about Factory design pattern(s).

See:

- [Factory (object-oriented programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming))
- [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)
- [Abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

For the sake of good OO practice I'd use an interface:

```
interface Fruit {

  void write(Writer out);

  ...
}  // Fruit
```

an abstract implementation of it:

```
public abstract class AbstractFruit implements Fruit {

  Data data;

  public void write(Writer out) {
    ...
  }

  ...
}  // AbstractFruit
```

```
public classe Apple extends AbstractFruit implements Fruit {
  ...
}
```

```
public classe Mango extends AbstractFruit implements Fruit {
  ...
}
```

and for the sake of [type safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) I'd use specific `get...()` methods (as it is often [done in the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicIconFactory.html#method.summary)):

```
public class FruitFactory {

  public static Fruit getApple() {
     Fruit a = new Apple()
     ...
     return a;
  }

  public static Fruit getMango() {
     Fruit m = new Mango()
     ...
     return m;
  }
}  // FruitFactory
```

or an `enum`:

```
interface Fruit {

  enum Type {
    APPLE,
    MANGO 
  }

  void write(Writer out);

  ...
}  // Fruit
```

```
public class FruitFactory {

  public static Fruit get(Fruit.Type fruitType) {

     switch (fruitType) {
        case Fruit.Type.APPLE:
          Fruit a = new Apple()
          ...
          return a;
          break;
        case Fruit.Type.MANGO:
          Fruit m = new Mango()
          ...
          return m;
          break;
        default:
          throw new FruitTypeNotSupported/* Runtime, i.e. unchecked */Exception();
          break; 
     }
  }  // get(...)
}  // FruitFactory
```

See the API documentation for [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html):

> Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method [...] throws clause

Answer (score -1):

First of all I would have your Factory have static create.  Then in the create do item instanceof Fruit then create the fruit thread.  else if item instanceof Vegetable then do vegetable thread.

Comment: While static methods are typical with Factories, keep in mind that if you don't use a static method, you can have multiple instances of Factories, which can be useful when trying to swap out factories.  The code without static is basically the same, one just needs to reuse the same instance.

Comment: No I wasn't, but I see that my answer has a down vote too.